# Django get attribtues of foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have an intermediate model -

```
class Link_Book_Course(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    image = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null=True)

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.date_created = datetime.now()
        super(Link_Book_Course,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

and I need to get the book name and title (which are attributes of Book) from a specified Link_Book_Course.

This is what I've come up with, but it doesn't work- instances don't have access to the manager apparently -

```
storedCourse = Link_Book_Course.objects.filter(course__name= nameAndNumberStore[0] + nameAndNumberStore[1])
        storedLink = Link_Book_Course.objects.filter(course = storedCourse)[0]
        storeOfAuthorNames = storedLink.objects.values('book__author')
        storeOfBookNames = storedLink.objects.values('book__title')
```

EDIT-
Nevermind, I've figured it out- for reference sake- you can't get attributes through a foreign key relationship.

Instead I filtered the Books that had the course that the user searched for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an even easier way!

```
>>> course = Course.objects.filter(name= nameAndNumberStore[0] + nameAndNumberStore[1])
>>> links = course.link_book_course_set.all()
>>> BookAuthorNames = [(link.book.title, link.book.author) for link in links]
(('Book1','Author1'),('Book2','Author2'),...)
```

Remember, the django ORM is powerful!